# Can I do basic maths in Bash?

Tags: bash, ssh

I was wondering, is it possible to do simple maths in bash? I'm thinking something like, =25-5 would print out 20 or something.

Can this be done easily?

Thank you

Comment: [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/44425)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just type `bc` into the terminal. Then type all the math stuff in after that.

`bc` stands for "**b**asic **c**alculator"

Then type `quit` and enter to exit.

Comment: Just for clarity it would be like that :  echo 25-5 | bc

Comment: For some math problems, you may need to wrap it in quotes, such as `echo '0.6 * 12' | bc`

Comment: you might also need to add scale to get floating point precision  working i.e. `echo "scale=2;557/3672" | bc`

Answer (score 77):

If we are really talking about Bash, not Bourne Shell (sh) or other shells, it's easy.

Bash can compute basic expressions with $((expression)) and here's an example on how you might like to use it:

```
 a=3
 b=4
 c=$((7*a+b))
 echo $c
```

or for interactive use, just

```
 echo $((7*3+4))
```

Comment: It does seem to be proper bash, since that works. I am ssh-ing into one of my universities clusters

Comment: The `$((expression))` syntax is part of the POSIX `sh` standard, and derived from `ksh`.

Comment: Bash can only do integer arithmetic.  It cannot do floating point arithmetic like ksh93 or zsh

Comment: This should've been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

There are a number of command-line utilities for doing simple calculations:

```
$ expr 100 \* 4
400

$ echo '100 * 4' | bc
400
```

to name just two of them.  Be careful doing multiplication as if you don't escape your * the shell may try and interpret it as a wildcard.

Answer (score 11):

Another is AWK:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print 4 + 3 / 12}'
```

Answer (score 9):

Well your question is answered, but consider this:

Most of the linux distros have python preinstalled, so why not use it?

Just type

```
python
```

in the terminal and then do all the arithmetic you want, like

```
2+2
```

Will output 4 :)

You can also do this directly from terminal with the `-c` python argument.

```
python -c 'print 2+2'
```

Comment: On my computer, typing `python` takes nearly two seconds to start. Rather annoying if you just want to do something simple like 2+2.

Comment: use python3 if you don't want float rounding. e.g. `2 / 30` (python: `0`) (python3: `0.06666666666666667`)

Comment: and if you only have python3 installed, but want rounding, use `2//30` or `int(2/30)`

Answer (score 3):

Or Ruby. :)

Although it may not come pre-installed, it is pretty quick.

Type `irb`, then `2+2`.

Or just `ruby -e 'p 2+2'`

Answer (score 3):

Perl is another option:

```
perl -E 'say 1/7'
```

outputs

```
0.142857142857143
```